# add protocol to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a protocol in Objective-C. I am, in another class, trying to add an object that implements this protocol to an NSMutableDictionary.

```
- (void) addValue:(NSString*)myString withObject:(id<MyProtocol>*)protocolThing
{
    [dictionary insertValue:protocolThing inPropertyWithKey:myString];
}
```

This gives me an error saying "Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'id' is disallowed with ARC"

How can I do this?

This is coming from Java, where I can declare an interface and then treat objects that implement that interface as regular objects and then add them to HashMaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `id<MyProtocol>` is already a pointer type. Change your signature to

```
- (void) addValue:(NSString*)myString withObject:(id<MyProtocol>)protocolThing
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: Works, thanks. Can't mark it correct yet. Its my first time asking on this site.

Answer (score 1):

When using `id` you do not use a *

Use this:

```
- (void) addValue:(NSString*)myString withObject:(id<MyProtocol>)protocolThing
```